# Passing a div value to a jQuery function inside Fancybox 2

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox-2

I load this content from `test.php`into Fancybox:

```
<form class="msgarea" action="" method="post">
            <textarea id="usermsg" cols="35" rows="4"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
</form> 

$("#submitmsg").click(function(){
    var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
    alert(clientmsg);
});
```

The `clientmsg` val alerts nothing, while any other jQuery function works fine. When I just call `test.php` directly and not inside fancybox then it works fine. What could be the problem?

This is how I call Fancybox if it's matter:

**EDIT:**

The index.php where I call test.php looks like this:

```
<img src="profileimage.jpg" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="test.php?user=123">

$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                        'type':'ajax',
                        "autoScale": false
                    });
    });
```

So when anyone click on the profileimage, the profile is shown from test.php into fancybox and I want the user to be able to send messages from the msgarea

**EDIT 2:**

Now inside index.php I changed it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        'type':'ajax',
        "autoScale": false
    });
    $('.msgarea').on('click', '#submitmsg', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
        alert(clientmsg);
    });
});
```

But it's not working :/

Comment: Where do you have the javascript function living? Try adding it to your test.php page.

Comment: It's [working fine](http://jsfiddle.net/gvajbqnb/). Have you tried adding your `.click` snipped into your `.ready` function? You should show how everything is structured.

Comment: inside fancybox @Jonast92

Comment: @Matt123456 Why on earth would you do that? Please, share the full code showing how.

Comment: It is allready inside test.php @remixdesign Like many other jQuery functions and they are all working inside fancybox except passing div values.

Comment: @Matt123456 We're not going to be able to help you unless you post a live demo. -- are there no errors in your developer tools?

Comment: I edited the question and added the most importent code but I don't think this is gona help :/

Comment: which jquery version do you use? any console errors?

Comment: It's ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js and I get no errors

Comment: your code inside the edit is still wrong. tried replacing '.msgarea' with 'document' ?

Comment: Yes tryed this way first and then .msgarea, both not working, it can only be the fault of fancybox right? I allready had some other problems with it

Comment: can u put a console.log('test') after your fancybox code? and check the console if it's shown? else your problem is indeed inside your fancybox function. u can also try to open ur side in internet explorer - it often shows more errors than chrome/firefox does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68424/discussion-between-gulty-and-matt123456).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not alerting because the id  #submitmsg doesnt exist since it's loaded asynchronous.

You need to use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitmsg', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
  alert(clientmsg);
});
```

document is just a working example - you should use a parent element instead to make this faster.

if it's not working debug it by putting console.logs before your fancybox, after ur fancybox and inside your click event. if it triggers inside the click event the code works and the problem is your markup. make sure there are no double ID's since they are unique.

Comment: This way it alerts nothing too :/ I also tryed: $('.msgarea').on('click', '#submitmsg', function(){

Comment: The code snipped is actually working fine. There's something wrong with the structure of the code.

Comment: oh well, I thought his JS would be inside a JS file not inline. Inside of an external file it wouldnt work like this.. try to put my JS code in your document ready func below your fanybox stuff..

Comment: But the fancybox code is in index.php, not test.php I tryed your new code inside test.php below everything but it's also not working, I guess it's the fancybox fault

Comment: as I said. put it in the index.php inside the domready func. my code doesnt have to be inside of the test.php.

Comment: I did, check out the new edit, is it right this way?

Comment: @Matt123456 you don't need to place any jQuery code inside test.php since you are calling it via ajax. You can place the code inside the fancybox `afterShow` callback instead.